# Determining if a function described by a Taylor series has a relative extremum at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have a very easy question from the 2004 BC2 (Form B) AP Calculus exam. The question is:

> $f$ is a function with derivatives of all orders for all real numbers. The third-degree Taylor polynomial for $f$ about $x=2$ is given by 
>   $$T(x)=7-9(x-2)^2-3(x-2)^3$$
>   b) [...] Determine whether $f(2)$ is a relative maximum, minimum, or neither, and justify your answer.

To solve this, I used the second derivative test for relative extremum:

> Since $f'(2)=T'(2)=2$ and $f''(0)=T''(2)=-18<0$, $f$ has a relative maximum at $x=2$.

I was thinking, though, what if I used the first derivative test for relative extremum instead?

> ```
>    x         2
>      <–––––––|–––––––>
> T'(x)    +   0   –
> ```
>
> Since the first 3 derivatives of $f(x)$ equal those of $T(x)$ around $x=2$, and $T'(x)$ changes from positive to negative at $x=2$, $f$ has a relative maximum there.

Now first of all, of course the second method is longer. However, I think it may also be incorrect, or at least require further justification. I do not think, though, that further justification is needed since $f$ does indeed equal $T$ for those first three derivatives at $x=2$ by definition.

Of course, that last statement of mine may very well be wrong. So, my question is, what is wrong with the second method for determining that $f$ has a relative maximum at $x=2$?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the reason is fairly simple:

The given Taylor Polynomial is not a series, so its interval of convergence is just the center—2 in this case.

Therefore, without further proof/explanation, one could not use $T’$ to determine if $f’$ is positive or negative at any point other than the center ($x=2$).

Comment: A polynomial is a power series that converges on all of $\Bbb R$, so your reasoning here is incorrect.

Comment: 5 years later! Yes a polynomial is a power series that converges on the real line; but -- though not stated the best -- the point here was that $T$ doesn't *necessarily* converge to $f$ at $x = 2$ on a nonempty open interval.

Comment: Some bot modified the question today, so it moved to the front page. Convergence of the Taylor series to $f$ is irrelevant. All you need is that the error between $f$ and $T$ is small compared to $(x-3)^3$. The fact that $T$ has a local maximum at $x=3$ therefore tells you that $f$ does as well.